# plupload should save large and small image

Tags: php, plupload

I am using plupload to save multiple images, I want to store same image with 2 sizes, small image for thum and large image to display in large.

How plupload will store 2 sizes of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier implementing what you need in the server side...

For the plupload; you can make use of the function:

```
  resize : {width : 500, height : 600, quality : 90},
```

You should be able to achieve what you need if you also made use of the events such FileUploaded to reupload the same uploaded file but with different parameters.

Here take a look at this discussion; it should guide you to the right path

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=555